# SharePoint 2013 Logo

Tags: site-logo

I added Company_Logo.jpg file to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\Logo` on both WFE and then went to Site Settings > and put `/_layouts/images/logo/company_logo.jpg` but it says file not found. If I put the whole url in address bar then I get 304 (from fiddler). What is the issue?

Comment: /_layouts/images/logo/company_logo.jpg perhaps?

Comment: I tried this and it works in all browser.../_layouts/15/images/logo/SmallLogo.jpg

Comment: You can also try to close the borwser and re open a fresh session of it

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE: I tried clearing cache from IE but and all i see is X for the picture. however, FF and Chrome is displaying the logo.

Comment: what is IE version? if you right click on the X  and properties...what address is that? also what happen when you browser directly to image http://url/_layouts/15/images/logo/SmallLogo.jpg

Comment: I put http://inside.hm.com/_layouts/15/images/logo/company_Logo.jpg and same. All I see X. right click properties says not available, dimension 68x30 (which is not correct). However, FF and chrome shows the logo. It's IE 11. I even added the site to the compatibility view and added to local intranet list.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to go to the developer tool (F12) f a browser and see what is the URL it is taking when it is saying file not found. So that you can understand what to give.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: /_layouts/15/images/logo/Company_Logo.jpg worked but only Chrome shows the logo and IE does not show the logo. I tried clearing cache and CTRL+F5 and no change in IE.

Comment: i suggest you to form a full url of the image and type it in the browser's address bar and hit enter. Do it both in chrome and IE. then you will figure out what is the issue.